# NetBeans IDE 15 adds x: before println() statement

Tags: java, netbeans

I have just begun to learn java with netbeans, and I noticed when I add println() it actually appears as

```
 System.out.println(x:"My text goes in here")
```

The x: appears automatically, and I was wondering what this means, is it a shortcut I can use? Or does it mean I did something wrong?

Comment: It's just displaying the name of the [parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String-).